# Why does Greenshot not work on some application?

Tags: greenshot

I would like to use greenshot on some application.
It works when I press print to get the screenshot selection, but on virtual box (clicked on the titlebar) it does not work. (Yes I am outside of the guest and not inside)
I must press on the taskbar and press print in order to get the selection that I finally use on the Virtual Box Window.

Is there are any hidden configuration?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I believe that unless you disable pointer integration, all keyboard input is sent to the VM, whether you clicked inside or not. Maybe even with pointer integration disabled.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the virtual box is running with administrator privileges, while Greenshot is not. So when the virtual box window is active, Windows will not notify Greenshot about the hotkey being pressed.

One workaround for this is to run Greenshot with administrator privileges.

See Greenshot's FAQ page for more details: [Why does the Print key not work in some windows?](http://getgreenshot.org/faq/why-does-the-print-key-not-work-in-some-windows/)